# Change Title of Action Bar from Fragmetn to Activity

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-support-library

I have One MainActivity with Button A to navigate to Fragment A and initiall Title Set as
 "This is Main Title"

When I click Button A, Following Code gets Executed

```
   getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Profile");
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container,new TrialProfile()).addToBackStack(null).commit();
```

and Now the Title Bar Text chnage to "Profile" But The Problem is When I press Back Button, The Title remains Same. I want it to change to Original One i.e  "This is Main Title"

Can you please help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

call this again on your current activity in oncreate method

```
getSupportActionBar().setTitle("This is Main Title");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(getActivity()).setTitle("Profile");
```

Answer (score 0):

To Change the title of Action Bar from Fragment to Activity

Create a method in activity like below:

```
public void setTitleActionBar(String title) {
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title);
    }
```

Now you can call the method in fragment and activity for changing the title:

In Fragment:

```
  ((HomeActvitiy) getActivity()).setTitleActionBar("Fragment title");
```

In Activity call the method before fragment replace like below:

```
 setTitleActionBar("My Profile");
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.home_container, new MyProfileFragment())
                .commit();
```

I hope its work for you.